# NodeJS: Trying to get the key of a specific value

Tags: node.js, object, key

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var blu = {
  obj_name: foo,
  some_data: {
          data1: {
               bla1: -10,
               bla2: 20,
               bla3: 30
               },
          data2: {
               blo1: -10,
               blo2: -20,
               blo3: 30
               }
            },
   some_other_data: test
}
```

And my goal was to extract and operate on every positive value within the `some_data` portion of the object and to extract both the value and the key corresponding to this value, in my example:

> "bla2 for 10"
>   "bla3 for 30"
>   "blo3 for 30"

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to get the string for the key corresponding to the value. I've tried this:

```
Object.keys(blu.some_data).forEach(k => {
    Object.keys(blu.some_data[k]).forEach(p => {
      if (blu.some_data[k][p] > 0) {
        console.log(
          `${Object.keys(blu.some_data[k][p])} for ${blu.some_data[k][p]}`
        );
      }
    });
  });
```

And I correctly get the positive values but not the corresponding key:

> " for 10"
>   " for 30"
>   " for 30"

How can I print a specific key of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your console.log line should look like this

`` console.log(`${p} for ${blu.some_data[k][p]}`); ``

You want to print key name which is p.

Comment: Righhttt... what a dumb question... Thanks for your help Kieper. I still can't believe I couldn't get that ... What a dumb question... Goshhh.